# How do you use apt-get to only install critical security updates on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

How do you use apt-get to only install critical security updates on ubuntu?

We'd like to only upgrade packages that need to be upgraded for security reasons, without upgrading all other packages.

Comment: There is a great answer to this on askubuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/194/how-can-i-install-just-security-updates-from-the-command-line

Comment: Perhaps I'm stating the obvious, but if you are running a stable distribution, the only updates you get will be critical updates (mostly security, occasionally fixing crucial breakage in a package).

Comment: Two [duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/q/194/20358) [threads](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35825436/712526) (with different solutions & different explanations).

Comment: For Debian [check **debsecan**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35825436/4970442) ([homepage](https://security-team.debian.org/security_tracker.html)) and of course `unattended-upgrades` package.

Answer (score 43):

I read the apt-get man page carefully when I got tired of manually editing the sources.list every time I wanted to only apply security updates (that means the second time).

Figured this solution out:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/security.sources.list
```

Edit the latter to contain only security repositories, then:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -o Dir::Etc::SourceList=/etc/apt/security.sources.list
```

Tadaaaa... Scriptable stuff.

Comment: Very nice! You can also `grep security /etc/apt/sources.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/security.sources.list` to avoid manual editing.

Comment: Ressu shows a trick to do this in apt preferences by [pinning normal packages to a lower priority](http://askubuntu.com/a/272/20358), but that seems a bit hacky. YMMV

Comment: I prefer this to using `unattended-upgrades` because I don't like services restarting without permission.

Comment: i like how this doesn't involve fragile regexes. I also had to override Dir::Etc::SourceParts.Tweaked version:`grep -h security -R /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ | sudo tee /etc/apt/sec
    && sudo apt-get upgrade -o Dir::Etc::SourceParts='' -o Dir::Etc::SourceList=/etc/apt/sec
`

Answer (score 25):

Try the `unattended-upgrades` or any of the other methods listed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates). It can be used to configure automatic security updates (I believe it's used when asked during the installer) as well as other upgrades automatically.  See the [man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/unattended-upgrade.8.html) for more details.

Answer (score 20):

If you are just looking to do this quickly once, instead of creating a separate repository and scripting up some automation and all that. Great if you aren't supposed to be making changes while auditing a system or whatever.

These two commands will spit out the list. Pipe to wc -l to see how many are behind. ;-)

```
grep security /etc/apt/sources.list > /tmp/security.list
sudo apt-get upgrade -oDir::Etc::Sourcelist=/tmp/security.list -s
```

Still valid for older distros or if you have update repos off, but security on:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -s| grep ^Inst |grep Security
```

Answer (score 4):

What I do:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y --only-upgrade $( apt-get --just-print upgrade | awk 'tolower($4) ~ /.*security.*/ || tolower($5) ~ /.*security.*/ {print $2}' | sort | uniq )
```

*A small description of what happens in the 2nd command:*

`apt-get install -y --only-upgrade $(CREATE_LIST_WITH_SECURITY_UPDATES)` → Upgrade all packages in the list created with `CREATE_LIST_WITH_SECURITY_UPDATES` without asking for confirmation and make sure no new packages are installed.

Explanation of `CREATE_LIST_WITH_SECURITY_UPDATES`:

- `apt-get --just-print upgrade` → Show all packages of which there is a upgrade available
- `awk 'PARSING_COMMANDS'` → Parse the output in such a way that the output is transformed in to a list of lines that contain the packages that should be updated
- `sort | uniq` → Sort the list alphabetically and filter out packages mentioned twice *(`uniq` doesn`t work correctly without sorting first)*

Explanation of `PARSING_COMMANDS`:

- `awk 'tolower($4) ~ /.*security.*/ || tolower($5) ~ /.*security.*/` → Check if either the 4th or 5th column in the output contains `security`. By using `tolower` we make sure that it doesn't matter whether `security` contains low or high case chars.
  *(Security updates will always have `security` in the first 4th or 5th column)*
- `{print $2}'` → If we found that it's a security update using the command above, print the 2nd column (which is the package name). If it's not a security update this `print $2` will not be executed and the line will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it will work, but apt has it's sources in /etc/apt/sources.list and/or /etc/sources.list.d/

Why not edit the file, and comment all lines that are not part of the security updates ?

The security lines for apt should be something like this:

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu ..... ..... ...

Leave those lines alone and comment all the others.